# PHP : why is the first record not being displayed when I use 'while' to show the results?

Tags: php, mysql

Why is the first record in my query not being displayed when I use 'while' to show the results?

For example, `user_id 1` logs in and the `contact_id` 5 and 6 are displayed with my echo at the end with:

```
echo "contact is " . $row["contact_id"];
```

Here's my code :

```
<?php 
require('dbConnect.php');

//I have a contacts table like this :

//contact_auto_inc     user_id     contact_id       
//      1              1             3
//      2              1             5
//      3              2             1
//      4              3             5
//      5              3             2
//      6              1             6

//The user logs in and their user_id is displayed at the top of the page with code like the following :

//use the variables we created earlier
session_start();
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
echo "user id is " . $user_id . "<br>"; 

//So if user_id 1 logs in, we see at the top of the page "user id is 1"

//I want to display the list of contacts for the logged in user_id

$select_from_contacts_table = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE user_id = '$user_id'";

//get the result of the above

$result=mysqli_query($con,$select_from_contacts_table);

//get every other record in the same row as that particular user_id
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

// get the matching contact_id in each row
//$contact_id = $row["contact_id"];

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //$contact_id=$rows['contact_id'];
    echo "contact is " . $row["contact_id"]  . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: You are fetching (and overwriting...) the first row right before the loop.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every call is a decrement to the pointer. Remove the first call:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

After this, you are again calling the same line in `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Because of this line here

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

You are not displaying this row.